# Getting the error "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection as array" when running queries in transaction block

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Below the code is giving the error in `RegisterController` when signingup.

```
protected function create( array $data ) {

        $company = null;
        $user_id = 0;

        DB::transaction( function ( $data ) {
            // Step 1 - Create User
            $user = User::create( [
                'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
                'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
                'job_title'  => $data['email'],
                'phone'      => $data['email'],
                'email'      => $data['email'],
                'status'     => 0,
                'password'   => Hash::make( $data['password'] ),
            ] );

            // Create the Company
            $user_id = $user->id;

            if ( $user_id > 0 ) {
                $company = Company::create( [
                    'user_id'  => $user_id,
                    'name'     => $data['company_name'],
                    'address'  => $data['address'],
                    'city'     => $data['company_city'],
                    'state'    => $data['state'],
                    'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
                    'country'  => $data['country'],
                    'notes'    => $data['notes'],
                    'status'   => 0,
                ] );

                if ( $company->id > 0 ) {
                    return $user;
                }
            }
        } );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB::transaction` method passes the connection as the first argument to the closure you provide. You want to add `$data` to the anonymous function's scope. You can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-179).

You want:

```php
        DB::transaction(function () use ($data) {
            ....
```

By passing `$data` as an argument to the closure, what you are actually getting as `$data` in the closure is the connection the transaction is being performed on.